# Do I need a Ruby database client for mongodb when I have mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I've been working on Rails apps with traditional databases, read SQL databases. Am trying to get myself familiar with NoSQL particularly MongoDB. 
I need to get a logical mapping between ActiveRecord and Mongoid. In the apps i've worked on in the past, My stack was: ActiveRecord, the pg gem (postgresql client) and postgresql, as the persistent data store. In the NoSQL app, I have Mongoid, and MongoDB. Do i need an equivalent of the pg gem or does mongoid take care of all that?

Comment: no you don't need the pg gem at all to use mongodb
check out the docs to get going http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html

Comment: so you're saying that mongoid "talks" to the database directly?

Comment: yes, mongoid does the work of (pg + AR) combined

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of `pg` in the MongoDB stack is `mongo`, the MongoDB Ruby driver.

https://rubygems.org/gems/mongo

Mongoid depends on `mongo` and uses `mongo` for low level operations (CRUD, etc.).